# How to use pydoc to generate a list of methods and properties in a Python file

Tags: python, introspection, pydoc

I have some classes that I wrote, and in some of them I did add some docs strings, like in the class header.

Now I would like to use pydoc, to generate documentation, but I realized that pydoc won't print anything unless I actually write the doc part inside the class, which is not what I want.

Is there a way to have pydoc generate a list of all the properties, methods and their type, including the type of the parameter required (if any), and the type of the return (if any)?

If I have a class like this:

```
class myclass(object):

    def __init__(anumber=2, astring="hello"):
        self.a = anumber
        self.b = astring

    def printme(self):
        thestring = self.a + self.b + "\nthat's all folks\n"
        return thestring

    def setvalues(self, a_number, a_string):
        self.a = a_number
        self.b = a_string
```

I would like to print something that includes the class name, class method, datatype:

```
class name
what parameters it takes in the init and the type of the parameters

method name
what parameters it takes and the type of the parameters
what value return and its type.
```

I believe pydoc won't do that. Is there any other way to do so?

I can add the doc strings for explanation later, but first of all, I would like to print out what is in my modules, to know what it takes, what it returns and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Pydoc should provide you the skeleton details, the same as `help(myclass)`, this will show you the function signatures of your class without any docstrings. You can use pydoc module to get this help information:

```
$ pydoc MyClass.myclass
Help on class myclass in MyClass:

class myclass(builtins.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(anumber=2, astring='hello')
 |  
 |  printme(self)
 |  
 |  setvalues(self, a_number, a_string)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

You can do this programmatically with the `pydoc` module:

```
>>> import pydoc
>>> import MyClass
>>> h = pydoc.plain(pydoc.render_doc(MyClass))
>>> print h
```